# How to name a variable that is a copy of a parameter?

Tags: java, parameters, naming-conventions

I have a method that will process a `Collection<Nodes>` that is passed in as a parameter. This `Collection` will be modified, therefore I thought it would be good to first make a copy of it. How do I name the parameter and local variable, e.g. `nodes` in the example below?

```
List<Nodes> process(Collection<Nodes> nodes) {
  List<Nodes> nodes2 = new ArrayList<>(nodes);
  ...
}
```

As another example consider the following where the variable is an `int` parsed from a `String` parameter:

```
public void processUser(final String userId) {
  final int userId2 = Integer.parseInt(userId);
  ...
```

Comment: What about a prefix. node2 is saying nothing but nodeCpy for example would. Will you still need the copy? Only copy the Collection if you really need it. Otherwise it's unused code.

Comment: I'm very sure there is no naming convention for a copy of parameter. I would also use `nodeCpy` as @sascha10000 suggested.

Comment: Opinion-based in perfect purity. However, as the reader of the code will probably be concerned with the method body mostly, I'd go for the logical name to understand the code in the *copy*. Assuming a concept like a list of my cars, I'd go for parameter name like myCarsIn, myCarsParm, myCarsImmutable, and name the copy myCars. (And BTW: the name "nodes" does not help the reader - is there no logical concept that these nodes share?)

Comment: Since we don't know how your code works, what your method does, what your nodes are and why you need to copy them I don't think we can give you better ideas how to name your parameter.

Comment: I always learned that you should first and foremost keep your interfaces clean. So don’t change the parameter name for this cause. For the variable, you’re describing it as a local copy for modification. `localCopyOfNodesForModification` is obviously too long, but I might suggest `localNodes`, `nodesCopy` (as already discussed) or `modifiableNodes`. Whatever works for you is fine.

Comment: @naXa this question is a poor fit for Programmers - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see [On the troubles of naming and terminology](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6583/31260) Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A good approach to the name variables problem is to use names that suggest the actual meaning of the variable. In your example, you are using names that do not say anything about the method functionality or variables meaning, that's why it is hard to pick a name.

There are many cases like yours in the JDK, e.g. [`Arrays#copyOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(U[],%20int,%20java.lang.Class)):

```
public static <T,U> T[] copyOf(U[] original, int newLength, Class<? extends T[]> newType) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    T[] copy = ((Object)newType == (Object)Object[].class)
        ? (T[]) new Object[newLength]
        : (T[]) Array.newInstance(newType.getComponentType(), newLength);
    System.arraycopy(original, 0, copy, 0,
                     Math.min(original.length, newLength));
    return copy;
}
```

In this case they call the parameter `original` and the local variable `copy` which perfectly expresses that the returned value is a copy of the parameter. Precisely, copying is what this method does and it is named accordingly.

Using the same reasoning for your case (consider refactoring to give more meaningful names to your method and variables) I would name your local copy of `nodes` something like `processedNodes`, to express what that variable is and to be consistent with your method's name.

**Edit:**

The name of the new method you added in your edit does not provide hints about what it does either. I'll assume that it modifies some properties (maybe in a database) of the user whose id is passed via parameter.

If that is the case (or similar), I think that an appropriate approach you 
could apply would be that every method should have a single responsibility. According to your method's name it should process the user, for that you need an `int userId`. The responsibility of parsing an `String userId` should be out of the scope of this method.

Using the proposed approach has, among others, the following advantages:

- Your class won't change if you have to add additional validation to your input.
- Your class won't be responsible for handling `NumberFormatException` which must be the application responsibility.
- Your `processUser` method won't change if you have to handle different types of inputs (e.g. `float userId`).

Answer (score 6):

It ultimately comes down to what you want to communicate to future programmers.  The computer obviously doesn't care; it's other people you're talking to.  So the biggest factor is going to be what those people need to know:

- What is the logical (abstract, conceptual) *meaning* of this variable?
- What aspects of how this variable is used could be confusing to programmers?
- What are the most important things about this variable?

Looking at your first example, it's kind of hard to understand enough about your program to really choose a good name.  The method is called `process`; but methods generally speaking implement computational processes, so this name really doesn't tell me anything at all.  What are you processing?  What is the process?  Who are you processing it for, and why?  Knowing what the method does, and the class it's in, will help to inform your variable name.

Let's add some assumptions.  Let's say you're building an application that locates Wi-fi access points in a building.  The `Node` in question is a wireless node, with subclasses `Repeater`, `AccessPoint`, and `Client`.  Let's also say it's an online-processed dataset, so the collection of nodes given may change at any time in response to a background thread receiving updates in what nodes are currently visible.  Your reason for copying the collection at the head of the method is to isolate yourself from those changes for the duration of local processing.  Finally, let's assume that your method is sorting the nodes by ping time (explaining why the method takes a generic `Collection` but returns the more specific `List` type).

Now that we better understand your system, let's use that understanding to choose some names that communicate the *logical intention* of your system to future developers:

```
class NetworkScanner {
    List<Node> sortByPingTime(Collection<Node> networkNodes) {
        final ArrayList<Node> unsortedSnapshot;

        synchronized(networkNodes) {
            unsortedSnapshot = new ArrayList<>(networkNodes);
        }

        return Utils.sort(unsortedSnapshot, (x,y) -> x.ping < y.ping);
    }
}
```

So the method is `sortByPingTime` to define what it does; the argument is `networkNodes` to describe what kind of node we're looking at.  And the variable is called `unsortedSnapshot` to express two things about it that aren't visible just by reading the code:

- It's a *snapshot* of something (implying that the original is somehow volatile); and
- It has no order that matters to us (suggesting that it might have, by the time we're done with it).

We could put `nodes` in there, but that's immediately visible from the input argument.  We could also call this `snapshotToSort` but that's visible in the fact that we hand it off to a `sort` routine immediately below.

This example remains kind of contrived.  The method is really too short for the variable name to matter much.  In real life I'd probably just call it `out`, because picking a good name would take longer than anyone will ever waste figuring out how this method works.

Other related notes:

- Naming is inherently a bit subjective.  My name will never work for everyone, especially when multiple human languages are taken into account.
- I find that the best name is often no name at all.  If I can get away with making something anonymous, I will--this minimizes the risk of the variable being reused, and reduces symbols in IDE 'find' boxes.  Generally this also pushes me to write tighter, more functional code, which I view as a good thing.
- Some people like to include the variable's type in its name; I've always found that a bit odd because the type is generally immediately obvious, and the compiler will usually catch me if I get it wrong anyway.
- "Keep it Simple" is in full force here, as everywhere.  Most of the time your variable name will not help someone avoid future work.  My rule of thumb is, name it something dumb, and if I ever end up scratching my head about what something means, choose that occasion to name it something good.

Answer (score 3):

I used to give names, which reflect and emphasize the major things. So a potential reader (including myself after a couple of months) can get immediately, what is done inside the method just by its signature.

The API in discussion receives an **input** , does some **processing** and returns the **output**. These are the three main things here.

If it is not important, what processing is done and what is the type of input, the most generic is this form:

```
List<Nodes> process(Collection<Nodes> input) {
  List<Nodes> output = new ArrayList<>(input);
  ...
}
```

and

```
public void process(final String input) {
    final int output = Integer.parseInt(input);
    ...
```

If it is important to provide more information about processing and type of an input, names like: *processCollection*, *inputCollection* and *processUser*, *inputUserId* are more appropriate, but the local variable is still the *output* - it is clear and self-explained name:

```
List<Nodes> processCollection(Collection<Nodes> inputCollection) {
  List<Nodes> output = new ArrayList<>(inputCollection);
  ...
}
```

and

```
public void processUser(final String inputUserId) {
    final int output = Integer.parseInt(inputUserId);
    ...
```

It depends on the use case and sometimes it is even more appropriate to elaborate the processing, which is done: *asArray* or *asFilteredArray* etc instead of *processCollection*.

Someone may prefer the **source-destination** terminology to the **input-output** - I do not see the major difference between them. If this serves telling the method story with  its title, it is good enough.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you are going to do with the local variable.

For example in the first example it seems that is likely that variable `nodes2` will actually be the value returned in the end. My advice is then to simply call it `result` or `output`.

In the second example... is less clear what you may want to achieve... I guess that `userIdAsInt` should be fine for the local. However if an `int` is always expected here and you still want to keep the parameter as a String (Perhaps you want to push that validation out of the method) I think it is more appropriate to make the local variable `userId` and the parameter `userIdAsString` or `userIdString` which hints that `String`, although accepted here, is not the canonic representation of an userId which is an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

For sure it depends on the actual context. I would not use approaches from other programming languages such as `_` which is good for instance for naming bash scripts, IMO `my` is also not a good choice - it looks like a piece of code copied from tutorial (at least in Java).

The most simple solution is to name method parameter `nodesParam` or `nodesBackup` and then you can simply go with `nodes` as a copy or to be more specific you can call it `nodesCopy`.

Anyway, your method `process` has some tasks to do and maybe it is not the best place for making copies of the nodes list. You can make a copy in the place where you invoke the method, then you can simply use `nodes` as a name of your object:

```
List<Nodes> process(Collection<Nodes> nodes) {
  // do amazing things here
  // ...
}

// ...
process(new ArrayList<>(nodes))
// ...
```

Just my guess, you have got a collection and you want to keep the original version and modify the copy, maybe a real solution for you is to use [java.util.stream.Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html).

Comment: "You can make a copy in the place where you invoke the method, then you can simply use nodes as a name of your object:" I think this is a terrible idea. Every invoker has to know that he needs to make a copy. Not good practice.

Comment: @Roland that's why I put it in section "anyway" ;) I think the solution for you is functional programming, then you start with input array and after few operations you end up with what you want and your original array is unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, when naming the variable, I consider a few things.

1. How is the copy created? (Is it converted from one type to another?...)
2. What am I going to do with the variable?
3. Is the name short, but/and meaningful?

Considering the same examples you have provided in the question, I will name variables like this:

```
List<Nodes> process(Collection<Nodes> nodes) {
  List<Nodes> nodesCopy = new ArrayList<>(nodes);
  ...
}
```

This is probably just a copy of the collection, hence the name `nodesCopy`. Meaningful and short. If you use `nodesList`, that can mean it is not just a `Collection`; but also a `List` (more specific).

```
public void processUser(final String userId) {
  final int userIdInt = Integer.parseInt(userId);
  ...
```

The `String` `userId` is parsed and the result is an integer (`int`)! It is not just a copy. To emphasize this, I would name this as `userIdInt`.

It is better **not** to use an underscore `_`, because it often indicates instance variables. And the `my` prefix: not much of a meaning there, and it is *nooby* (`local` will do better).

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to method parameter naming conventions, if the thing a method parameter represents will not be represented by any other variable, use a method parameter name that makes it very clear what that method parameter is in the context of the method body. For example, `primaryTelephoneNumber` may be an acceptable method parameter name in a JavaBean setter method.

If there are multiple representations of a thing in a method context (including method parameters and local variables), use names that make it clear to humans what that thing is and how it should be used.  For example, `providedPrimaryTelephoneNumber`, `requestedPrimaryTelephoneNumber`, `dirtyPrimaryTelephoneNumber` might be used for the method parameter name and `parsedPrimaryTelephoneNumber`, `cleanPrimaryTelephoneNumber`, `massagedPrimaryTelephoneNumber` might be used for the local variable name in a method that persists a user-provided primary telephone number.

The main objective is to use names that make it clear to humans reading the source code today and tomorrow as to what things are.  Avoid names like `var1`, `var2`, `a`, `b`, etc.; these names add extra effort and complexity in reading and understanding the source code.

Don't get too caught up in using long method parameter names or local variable names; the source code is for human readability and when the class is compiled method parameter names and local variable names are irrelevant to the machine.